# Auto mounting of "identical" external USB drives in Ubuntu swaps the mount points

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb-storage, automount

I have 2 identical Western Digial Elements 1,5 TB external harddrives, but they are causing some problems when they mount. The problem is that the OS sees them as identical drives with the same identifier. I'll give an example.

```
HDD 1:
Location /dev/sdc

HDD 2:
Location /dev/sdd
```

So i edited /etc/fstab and mounted `/dev/sdc` to `/mnt/drive1`, and `/dev/sdd` to `/mnt/drive2`, and this works as expected. But once in a while after i reboot the OS i confused and HDD 2 is suddonly at `/dev/sdc` instead of `/dev/sdd`. So the wrong HDD is mounted to the wrong place. This of course is causing problems since the files and folders that i expect to be at `/mnt/drive1` actually are at `/mnt/drive2``

Is there a way for me to give the drives a different identifier so that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UUIDs instead of the /dev/... device names.

Do this:

```
sudo blkid
```

to get a list of UUIDs and then replace the /dev/sdc bit of fstab with UUID=xxx-xxx-xxxx

See [Ubuntu's UUID docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) for details.